# Mule JaxB unmarshalling failingto parse the ArrayList

Tags: java, jaxb, mule, xstream, mule-esb

I am trying a usecase that the actual XML to be transformed as Java Object by using xml-to-object-transformer> transformer in Mule3., no DW.  I ended up with a strange issue and pls chk if anyone can help.

To do that,

1. Generated a JAXB class using XJC JAXB API
2. Setting that class as alias class in the transformer to validate the data types
3. Do the xml-to-object-transformer with the above alias

**Code snippet of Mule**

```
<mulexml:xml-to-object-transformer driverClass="com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.Xpp3Driver" doc:name="XML to Object">
    <mulexml:alias class="com.test.jaxb.model.Root" name="root"  />
</mulexml:xml-to-object-transformer>
```

**Code snippet of XSD**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="customerDetails">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="customerDetail">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="customerName" type="xs:string" />
                                        <xs:element name="customerId" type="xs:unsignedShort" />
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**Code snippet of Root.Java [Generated by XJC]**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "customerDetails"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
public class Root {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected Root.CustomerDetails customerDetails;
    public Root.CustomerDetails getCustomerDetails() {
        return customerDetails;
    }

    public void setCustomerDetails(Root.CustomerDetails value) {
        this.customerDetails = value;
    }


    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "customerDetail"
    })
    public static class CustomerDetails {

        @XmlElement(required = true)
        protected List<Root.CustomerDetails.CustomerDetail> customerDetail;

        public List<Root.CustomerDetails.CustomerDetail> getCustomerDetail() {
            if (customerDetail == null) {
                customerDetail = new ArrayList<Root.CustomerDetails.CustomerDetail>();
            }
            return this.customerDetail;
        }


        @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
        @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
            "customerName",
            "customerId"
        })
        public static class CustomerDetail {

            @XmlElement(required = true)
            protected String customerName;
            @XmlSchemaType(name = "unsignedShort")
            protected int customerId;

            public String getCustomerName() {
                return customerName;
            }

            public void setCustomerName(String value) {
                this.customerName = value;
            }

            public int getCustomerId() {
                return customerId;
            }

            public void setCustomerId(int value) {
                this.customerId = value;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

**Test Message**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<customerDetails>
  <customerDetail>
  <customerName>TestUser1</customerName>
    <customerId>123</customerId>
  </customerDetail>
    <customerDetail>
  <customerName>TestUser2</customerName>
    <customerId>321</customerId>
  </customerDetail>
  </customerDetails>
</root>
```

**Expected output**
Java object

**But Actual output - Error receiving**

```
---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : customerName
class               : java.util.ArrayList
required-type       : java.util.ArrayList
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter
path                : /root/customerDetails/customerDetail/customerName
line number         : 5
class[1]            : com.test.jaxb.model.Root$CustomerDetails
converter-type[1]   : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
class[2]            : com.test.jaxb.model.Root
version             : 1.4.10
------------------------------- (com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException)
Payload               : org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.BufferInputStream@74447578
Transformer           : XmlToObject{this=47272cd3, name='XmlToObject', ignoreBadInput=false, returnClass=SimpleDataType{type=java.lang.Object, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}, sourceTypes=[SimpleDataType{type=java.lang.String, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}, SimpleDataType{type=[B, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}, SimpleDataType{type=java.io.InputStream, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}, SimpleDataType{type=org.w3c.dom.Document, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}, SimpleDataType{type=org.dom4j.Document, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}]}
Element               : /poc-json2xml-testFlow/processors/0 @ poc-json2xml-dummy:poc-json2xml-dummy.xml:29 (XML to Object)
Element XML           : <mulexml:xml-to-object-transformer driverClass="com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.Xpp3Driver" doc:name="XML to Object">
                        <mulexml:alias class="com.test.jaxb.model.Root" name="root"></mulexml:alias>
                        </mulexml:xml-to-object-transformer>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: customerName
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper.realClass(DefaultMapper.java:81)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DynamicProxyMapper.realClass(DynamicProxyMapper.java:55)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.PackageAliasingMapper.realClass(PackageAliasingMapper.java:88)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ClassAliasingMapper.realClass(ClassAliasingMapper.java:79)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ArrayMapper.realClass(ArrayMapper.java:74)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.SecurityMapper.realClass(SecurityMapper.java:71)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CachingMapper.realClass(CachingMapper.java:47)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.HierarchicalStreams.readClassType(HierarchicalStreams.java:29)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:72)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.addCurrentElementToCollection(CollectionConverter.java:98)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.populateCollection(CollectionConverter.java:91)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.populateCollection(CollectionConverter.java:85)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.unmarshal(CollectionConverter.java:80)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:70)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:503)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:429)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:281)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:70)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:134)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1486)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1466)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:1337)
at org.mule.module.xml.transformer.XmlToObject.transformMessage(XmlToObject.java:68)
at org.mule.transformer.AbstractMessageTransformer.transform(AbstractMessageTransformer.java:141)
at org.mule.transformer.AbstractMessageTransformer.transform(AbstractMessageTransformer.java:89)
at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.transformMessage(DefaultMuleMessage.java:1642)
at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.applyAllTransformers(DefaultMuleMessage.java:1545)
at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.applyTransformers(DefaultMuleMessage.java:1519)
at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.applyTransformers(DefaultMuleMessage.java:1511)
at org.mule.transformer.AbstractTransformer.process(AbstractTransformer.java:114)
at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:111)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:110)
at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:111)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
at org.mule.construct.DynamicPipelineMessageProcessor.process(DynamicPipelineMessageProcessor.java:55)
at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:111)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88)
at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.processBlocking(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:59)
at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.process(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:48)
at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:111)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
at org.mule.processor.AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.process(AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.java:52)
at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:111)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.processBlocking(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:57)
at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.process(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:48)
at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:111)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88)
at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:111)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
at org.mule.construct.AbstractPipeline$3.process(AbstractPipeline.java:232)
at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.HttpMessageProcessorTemplate.routeEvent(HttpMessageProcessorTemplate.java:73)
at org.mule.execution.AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase$1.process(AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.java:73)
at org.mule.execution.AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase$1.process(AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.java:60)
at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:16)
at org.mule.execution.CommitTransactionInterceptor.execute(CommitTransactionInterceptor.java:35)
at org.mule.execution.CommitTransactionInterceptor.execute(CommitTransactionInterceptor.java:22)
at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:30)
at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:14)
at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:67)
at org.mule.execution.ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.execute(ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.java:44)
at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:50)
at org.mule.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:40)
at org.mule.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:41)
at org.mule.execution.ExternalTransactionInterceptor.execute(ExternalTransactionInterceptor.java:48)
at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:28)
at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:13)
at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:110)
at org.mule.execution.AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.runPhase(AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.java:59)
at org.mule.execution.AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.runPhase(AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.java:36)
at org.mule.execution.PhaseExecutionEngine$InternalPhaseExecutionEngine.process(PhaseExecutionEngine.java:114)
at org.mule.execution.PhaseExecutionEngine.process(PhaseExecutionEngine.java:41)
at org.mule.execution.MuleMessageProcessingManager.processMessage(MuleMessageProcessingManager.java:32)
at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.DefaultHttpListener$1.handleRequest(DefaultHttpListener.java:135)
at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.GrizzlyRequestDispatcherFilter.handleRead(GrizzlyRequestDispatcherFilter.java:100)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.run0(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:119)
at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.access$100(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:31)
at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

---

Comment: Hi, is the stack trace complete?

Comment: @aled - Updated full trace.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is that you are using the  transformer, which doesn't know how to handle JAXB processing. You should try instead the [JAXB transformers](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/jaxb-transformers).

There is a previous similar answer for an older version of Mule: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20243878/721855

Comment: I am not able to open the "JAXB transformers" link, can you share it pls.  Also, I am using the same approach [alias class] only for the transformer as they have written in the post.

Comment: The link was broken. Sorry about that. I fixed it now.